# RGBELoader low quality of texture - 256 x 256

Tags: three.js

For some reason `RGBELoader()` generates 256x256 textures regardless of what the source is (4k). I tried using the `pmremGenerator` and it doesn't seem to work with or without it.

```
new RGBELoader()
                .setPath( './maps/' )
                .load( 'empty_warehouse_01_4k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

                        //texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
                        const envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular( texture ).texture;

                        scene.background = envMap; //or 'texture' to bypass pmremGenerator
                        scene.environment = envMap;

}

let pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer )
pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
```

Here's the result:

[image]

This is the 4k HDR quality:

[image]

The only example that has high quality background and environment map is this one but it uses `THree.CubeTextureLoader()` and it only takes LDR (.jpg).

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=env#webgl_materials_envmaps
[[Source]](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps.html)

Answer (score 2):

`RGBELoader` does not alter the resolution of your texture. The problem in your code is that the result of `PMREMGenerator` should not be used for `Scene.background`.

Besides, the renderer automatically preprocesses assigned HDR environment map with `PMREMGenerator` for PBR materials since `r131`. So when loading HDR environment maps via classes like `RGBELoader` or `EXRLoader`, there should be no reason for using `PMREMGenerator` on app level with latest releases.

Please use the official glTF example as a code template: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew `PMREMGenerator` was not needed but decided to try anyway. The example that you gave is what I've been using and it suffers from the low quality same issue. It uses `scene.background = texture;`. I guess I can use high-res jpg for the background but it still doesn't solve the issue with the low-res reflection map.